CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking) issue on codeigniter4 and vue3
I use codeigniter4 for backend and vue3 for frontend. In displaying the image in vue3 this issue appears:
Response was blocked by CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking)
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response.
Please help me to solve that problem.
This are my code:
(codeigniter)
public function show($id = null)
{
    $model = new Product();
    $data = $model->find($id);
    if ($data) {
        $data['product_photo'] = base_url('uploads/' . $data['product_photo']);
        $data['supplier_names'] = $this->getSupplierNamesForProduct($id);
        return $this->respond($data);
    }
        return $this->failNotFound('Product not found');
}

(vue)
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'ProductOverview',
    data() {
        return {
            productId: this.$route.params.id,
            product: {
                product_photo: '',
                // other product properties
            }
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
          axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/products/${this.productId}`)
          .then(res => {
               this.product = res.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error("There was an error fetching the product data:", error);
          });
        }
    }
};
</script>

I expect the CORB issue to be solve.

It really depends on the codeigniter version you're using. If its the latest one they added class to handle all the CORS stuff.
You can check the docs here
Check this config class alongside your route filters to see why the request is being blocked.
